# Jquery help needed for onbeforeunload event

Tags: asp.net, jquery, onbeforeunload

I am using jquery onbeforeunload event in asp.net application.
If i write event as given below then its working fine and display confirm dialog box.

```
var vGlobal = true;
var sMessage = "Leaving the page will lost in unsaved data!";
```

[ Working ]

```
> window.onbeforeunload = function() {
>   if (vGlobal == false) return
> sMessage; }
```

but its not working if i use bind method like as given below

[ Not working ]

```
$(window).bind("beforeunload", function(e) {
    if (vGlobal == false)
        return sMessage;
});
```

Anybody suggest me why its not working.Is there any difference between these two methods.

Code on aspx:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

[**CLICK ON THIS LINK TO SEE RUNNING EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/s6u4J/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [**updated version**](http://jsfiddle.net/s6u4J/4/)

You need to bind all the events inside document ready event.

Comment: Thanks rahul for reply.Actually problem was that i was using jquery version 1.3.2.Now i got v1.4.4 and its working fine.One more question Do we have write to all jquery code inside $(document).ready function??Is it must??

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the fact that `vGlobal` is `true` and you are checking `if (vGlobal == false)`, this smells like a $(document).ready() issue.

I.e. you should place the declaration inside a document.ready() handler as shown here:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).bind("beforeunload", function(e) {
        if (vGlobal == false)
            return sMessage;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no benefit in using jQuery to bind the event to the window - all you are doing is adding the overhead of having jQuery parse the window into a jQuery object, which you aren't even using.

Therefore, using:

```
window.onbeforeunload = handler;
```

Is preferable to using jQuery to bind this event.

You can still perform the binding inside of the document ready section:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    window.onbeforeunload = handler;
};
```

Comment: Actually, there is a benefit in using jQuery. If there are multiple declarations of `$(window).bind("event"...` then the function calls are stacked. `window.onbeforeunload = handler;` will just replace whatever was originally there.

Comment: But there aren't multiple event handlers in this scenario - and if there were you could still wrap all functions in a single event handler - so there really is no benefit.